# Python irc bot input

Tags: python, irc

ive been working on an irc bot and have run into a halt, i cant figure out how to accept input for arguments for a function, specifically my function add(), heres the function,

```
def add(x1,x2):
    xtot = x1 + x2
    ircsock.send("PRIVMSG "+ channel + " :Toatal =  %s.\n" % (xtot))
```

and heres how its called

```
if ircmsg.find('add.' + botnick) != -1:
    add()
```

i want to know how to attach input along side just running the function, as in add.mybot 1,2
instead of just add.mybot

Comment: you just want the values of x1 and x2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which library you are using, but I will suppose that ircmsg contains the input (otherwise, replace ircmsg by ircmsg.line/ircmsg.input/…

```
import re
if ircmsg.find('add.' + botnick) != -1:  #you find a line with add.mybot
    try:
        (x,y) = [int(i) for i in re.match(".*\((.*),(.*)\).*",a).groups()] #we try to retrieve what we want
        add(x, y)
    except:
        pass # or some logs
```

However, I think that the conversion should not be done here but in your `add` function (+ if you want to be able to add float for instance).

For instance:

```
import re
if ircmsg.find('add.' + botnick) != -1:  #you find a line with add.mybot
    try:
        (x,y) = re.match(".*\((.*),(.*)\).*",a).groups() #we try to retrieve what we want
        add(x, y)
    except:
        pass # or some logs
```

and

```
def add(x1,x2):
    if x1.isdigit() and x2.isdigit():
        xtot = int(x1) + int(x2)
        ircsock.send("PRIVMSG "+ channel + " :Toatal =  %s.\n" % (xtot))
    else:
        try:
            xtot = float(x1) + float(x2)
            ircsock.send("PRIVMSG "+ channel + " :Toatal =  %s.\n" % (xtot))
        except:
            pass #or send the concatenation x1+x2
```

Hope I am not mistaken.

Comment: Would you show me how you would add it into the add function?

Comment: Thank you so much, if i had 15 rep i would upvote you! So add.mybot(10,10) would run correctly? or would it be something different? i just started this yesterday.

Comment: Ive tried typing in add.mybot(2,2) and it wasnt working, im not sure if its because you add x and y instead of x1 and y1 or if im typing it incorrectly, would you mind helping me with this as well?

Comment: It's because in your question you said `add.mybot 1,2` not `add.mybot (1,2). Plus, my answer was only working for `add.mybot 1 2`! I have edited my answer. It works with regexp, but you can use split if you want. Something like `.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].split(',')` should work.